# Is there a way to calculate factorials of #s w/o a pre-determined amount of user input? i.e. will calculate 1!-7! w/o initializing 7 diff. variables

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to get rid of having to create 4 different `do-while` statements for each variable? For example, I would like to calculate `1!-7!` w/o initializing 7 diff. variables and initializing 7 different variables. Is this possible?

Below is an example of how I would like the program to initiate and what the output should be

```
./filename.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
The factorial 1! is 1
The factorial 2! is 2
The factorial 3! is 6
The factorial 4! is 24
…
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash    
on1=0          #initiating the 4 variables
on2=0          #possible to compress these into 1 variable?
on3=0
on4=0
fact1=1
fact2=1
fact3=1
fact4=1

echo -n "Enter numbers to find factorial : "      # gets user input of 4 #s
read n1 n2 n3 n4
on1=$n1
on2=$n2
on3=$n3
on4=$n4

while [ $n1 -ge  1 ]              # calculates first factorial
do                                #possible to only make 1 loop?
  fact1=`expr $fact1 \* $n1`      
  n1=`expr $n1 - 1`
done

while [ $n2 -ge  1 ]         # calculates second factorial
do
  fact2=`expr $fact2 \* $n2`
  n2=`expr $n2 - 1`
done

while [ $n3 -ge  1 ]        #calculates third factorial
do
  fact3=`expr $fact3 \* $n3`
  n3=`expr $n3 - 1`
done

while [ $n4 -ge  1 ]        # calculates fourth factorial
do
  fact4=`expr $fact4 \* $n4`
  n4=`expr $n4 - 1`
done

echo "The factorial $on1! is $fact1"        # outputs the four factorials
echo "The factorial $on2! is $fact2"        #possible to make only 1 echo?
echo "The factorial $on3! is $fact3"
echo "The factorial $on4! is $fact4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to process each of the arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    n=$1
    on=$n
    fact=1
    while [ $n -ge 1 ]
    do
        fact=$(expr $fact \* $n)
        n=$(expr $n - 1)
    done
    echo "The factorial of $on is $fact"
    shift # go to the next argument
done
```

Comment: What happens when n> 20?

Comment: @WalterA It overflow. If you want to be able to calculate really large factorials, you need to use a language with larger integers.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! I've only started learning shell scripting so I wasn't sure how the looping process would work.

Comment: This is a very common idiom for looping over the arguments to a script. I find it hard to believe it's not anywhere in the tutorials you're learning from.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, I tried a recursive solution:

```
 #!/bin/zsh
 function fact {
   if (($1 < 2))
   then
     echo 1
   else
     expr $1 '*' $(fact $(($1-1)))
   fi
 }
 for arg
 do
   fact $arg
 done
```

I first thought, it would blow up soon due to stack overflow, but it calculated happily even pretty large values (such as 200!) in quite short time (in zsh; didn't try it with other shells)!

Comment: Are the shell's integers large enough to hold 200!?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried this bit of code and I liked how it solves the problem recursively.

Comment: @Barmar: I just compared the output with a Ruby program for factorials (Ruby has infinite precision arithmetic), and the result is the same, at lesat up to `200!`.

Comment: This works in `zsh` because it has floating point arithmetic, and it automatically promotes integers to float when they overflow. But the results may not be accurate as a result, due to loss of precision.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't think this explains the result. Calculating 200! gives a result, which consists of 375 decimal digits, more than 300 of them significant - and I mean *correct* digits. To achieve such an accuracy with floating point arithmetic, would require a mantissa with more than 1000 bits, which certainly is not the case. But I now see, why it works: *Shell* arithmetic is done in the step `$((i - 1))` only, which involves only small digits. The multiplication is done using `expr`, and this has arbitrary precision. Hence, it would work in `bash` too, not only Zsh.

Comment: @user1934428 What version of `expr` has arbitrary precision? Just tried the version from coreutils 8.13: `xpr 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 + 1` **Numerical result out of range**

Comment: Mine is coreutils 8.24. I don't get the error message which you are quoting. It seems that this feature was introduced only recently! @LukeFord: Since my recursive version seems to run on your platform too, may I ask you which version of `expr ` **you** are using?

Comment: @Barmar: Mystery solved! From the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/expr): _When built with support for the GNU MP library, expr uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic_. So it's not related to the version. So my proposed solution is not as portable as I had hoped. If we want to solve this in a portable way, we have to use a suitable programming language, such as Ruby or Perl.